# libusb calls without sudo using udev-rules

Tags: linux, usb, udev

Tested on Kubuntu 16.04 64 bit only. I have an application which source is not under my control. It uses some libusb calls which ends up in e.g.:

```
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/001/031: Permission denied
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb requires write access to USB device nodes.
```

When running the above mentioned application as root, it works as expected.
When I change the permissions of the regarding file like:

```
sudo chmod a+w /dev/bus/usb/001/031
```

then the application will work with standard user rights (until I disconnect / reconnect my usb device).

Now I'm looking for a way, to e.g. automatically execute the `chmod a+w` each time when the specific usb device is plugged in.
Might this be possible by writing a specific udev rule?

Maybe other solutions the libusb calls without root rights?

**Solution:** Based upon David Grayson's answer, I'd now added an additional line with `SUBSYSTEM=="usb"` to my rule file. My rules file now finally looks like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1234", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5678", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1234", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5678", MODE="0666"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest that you add a new file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` named `usb.rules`.  It should have the following contents:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", MODE="0666"
```

This will make all USB devices readable and writable by all users.

You could also narrow it down to specific USB devices using `idVendor` and `idProduct` attributes mentioned in Ignacio's answer.

Comment: as I understand, the `MODE=` just changes the permissions of the `/dev/ttyACM…` file but not those of the entries in `/dev/bus/usb/…`

Comment: In the Unix world, "mode" is general term used and it refers to file permissions.  It does not refer to ACM devices.  I have used rules like this successfully with libusb before.  Did you try my rule?

Comment: Yeah, `SUBSYSTEM=="usb"` was the trick to make the following `MODE=…` and `GROUP=…` affect to `/dev/bus/usb/…`. Until before, I'd just used `SUBSYSTEM=="tty"`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Kubuntu 16.04 uses PolicyKit, put the following in a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d`, naming it similarly to the files that already exist there:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="xxxx", ATTRS{idProduct}=="xxxx", TAG+="uaccess", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
```

Replace the two sets of "xxxx" with the vendor ID and product ID of the device respectively.

Comment: Did you replug the device?

Comment: Yep, and als also added a `RUN+="…"` to make sure that the rule will be executed. Btw: IMHO the `ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE` is not longer required in 16.04, isn't it (I know such modem manager trouble from 14.04)?

Comment: adding `GROUP="plugdev"` seems also to change nothing

Comment: correction of the above comment: adding `GROUP="plugdev"` just changes the group of `/dev/ttyACM*` but not of `/dev/bus/usb/…`.

Answer (score 0):

Oldie but goldie. Help me to solve my issue with sharing the usb with virtual machines under AQEMU. Thanks a lot.
I added to the `/etc/udev/rules.d` file `usb.rules` with this line

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1234", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5678", MODE="0666"
```

and virtual machine can see USB stick being connected life.