# How to fix the usb.core.USBError of thermal printer connected to raspberry pi using USB port

Tags: python, printing, raspberry-pi, usb, raspbian

I'm having a problem in my thermal printer, I can't print but it's working.
I'm using esc-pos python module https://pythonhosted.org/python-printer-escpos/modules/escpos.html

this is my code

```
from escpos.connections import getUSBPrinter
printer = getUSBPrinter()(idVendor=0x0fe6, idProduct=0x811e, interface=98)
printer.text("Hello World")
printer.lf()
```

here's the error I encountered.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/pi/try thermal.py",
>   line 4, in 
>       printer = getUSBPrinter()(idVendor=0x0fe6, idProduct=0x811e, interface=98)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/escpos/connections.py", line
>   87, in **init**
>       self.**open()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/escpos/connections.py", line
>   106, in __open
>       if self._device.is_kernel_driver_active(0):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/usb/core.py", line 1061, in
>   is_kernel_driver_active
>       self._ctx.managed_open()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/usb/core.py", line 102, in
>   wrapper
>       return f(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/usb/core.py", line 120, in
>   managed_open
>       self.handle = self.backend.open_device(self.dev)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line
>   786, in open_device
>       return _DeviceHandle(dev)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line
>   643, in __init**
>       _check(_lib.libusb_open(self.devid, byref(self.handle)))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line
>   595, in _check
>       raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret]) usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)

The Thermal printer I'm using is, https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1799.html
https://www.adafruit.com/product/2751

I hope you guys can help me, I badly needed this on thesis and I'm only new to raspberry-pi.

Comment: You probably need some [udev rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40597515/4730685) that grant your user access to the USB device. Running as root should also work.

Comment: Hi sir @Erlkoenig, Thank you so much for your suggestion.
I searched how to create a udev rules, but I can't understand any of it :(. should I create a new file or edit an existing udev rule?

Comment: You need a new file, probably in `/etc/udev/rules.d`. Try running your program as root first to confirm this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: running my program as root is to run it in my rpi terminal right? I still got the same error.

Comment: Prefix the command with `sudo` to run it as root.

Comment: I did it and got this error. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "thermal.py", line 4, in <module>
    printer = getUSBPrinter()(idVendor=0x0fe6, idProduct=0x811e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/escpos/connections.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.initialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/escpos/commandset/generic.py", line 463, in initialize
    self.__write(self.__class__.__ESC + '@')
AttributeError: 'USBPrinter' object has no attribute '_Generic__write'
`

Comment: I keep on getting the error above, the getFilePrinter and getUSBprinter but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Don't know about that, maybe used the library wrong.

Comment: Sir @Erlkoenig, It's running now when I run it as root. But It's not running when I use python IDE. this is the error 
`usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)`

Comment: I found a tutorial here <https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installation.html#setup-udev-for-usb-printers> but I can't save my created new file in /etc/udev/rules.d.

Comment: The prompt pop-out and said I don't have a permission to create a new file.

Comment: Create the file in some user-writable location and copy it via `sudo cp <source> /etc/udev/rules.d`.

Comment: Then, [reload](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39371/357261) the udev rules.

Comment: I still got the same error, my udev rule is `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0fe6", ATTRS{idProduct}=="811e", MODE="0664"`
I followed what you've said, my new file has been save to `/etc/udev/rules.d` successfully. i reload and tried to reboot. But the error is still the same when I run it on my python IDE.

Comment: Try `MODE="0666"`.

Comment: You're welcome :) I summarized the comments into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Linux user doesn't have access to the USB device, so you need to create an udev rule to grant access.

Create a file `printer.rules` with the following contents:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0fe6", ATTRS{idProduct}=="811e", MODE="0666"
```

And copy it into the rules directory via `sudo`:

```sh
sudo cp printer.rules /etc/udev/rules.d
```

Then reload the udev rules:

```sh
udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger
```

Now, every user should have access to the printer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate this. Cheers! :))))))))